# loading icon on all ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax

I successfully have a page that makes 2 ajax requests when i change a combobox... 
I also got the loading div to work , but it seems to only be working on the first call, the second ajax div is refreshed after the div for the loading disappears ...

this is my code:

```
        /*first call----------*/
        $(document).ready(function()

        {

        $(".drop").change(function()

        {

        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){

        $("#wait").css("display","block");

        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

        $("#wait").css("display","none");

         });


        var id=$(this).val();
        var dataString = '1level='+ id;



        $.ajax

        ({

        type: "POST",

        url: "call2.php",

        data: dataString,

        cache: false,

        success: function(html)

        {

        $(".tab2").html(html);

        $(".tab1").text(id);

        $(".tab3").text("");


        /*second call*/
        $.ajax

        ({

        type: "POST",

        url: "names.php",

        data: dataString,

        cache: false,

        success: function(html)

        $("#names").css("display","block");

        $(".names").html(html);         
        {

        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){

        $("#wait").css("display","block");

        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

        $("#wait").css("display","none");

         });

        }

        });

        }

        })

        });

        });
```

I wanted to have the loading animation on every time data is being loaded and the 2nd one loads after the animation is stopped...

thanks in advance...;)

Comment: you don't need to run ajaxStart and ajaxComplete for every ajax request. Once is enough. Your code is so hard to read. You appear to have a syntax error inside your second ajax call success callback. (between the `function ()` and `{`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with this code. To begin with, all the extra spacing, new lines in places where there shouldn't be, improper indenting, etc lead to a syntax error in the success callback of the second ajax request. Additionally, ajaxStart and ajaxComplete are global ajax events that only need to be bound once, therefore it should be moved outside of the change event. After fixing these two issues and cleaning up the spacing and tabs, I ended up with this:

```
$("#wait").css("display", "block");
/*first call----------*/
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".drop").change(function () {

        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = '1level=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "call2.php",
            data: dataString,
            //cache: false, not needed for post requests
            success: function (html) {

                $(".tab2").html(html);
                $(".tab1").text(id);
                $(".tab3").text("");

                /*second call*/
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "names.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    //cache: false, not needed for post requests
                    success: function (html) { // the syntax error was here

                        $("#names").css("display", "block");
                        $(".names").html(html);
                        $("#wait").css("display", "none");

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: no doubt the codes is cleaner, but there are still some issues:First, i need that every time the combo is selected the loading appears, and is not, because you moved it to the beginning; and it still does't shoes the loading on the right times... it goes away and only about a second past the 2nd called is refreshed...but thanks for the cleaning help);

Comment: Kevin B helped cleaning the code but still the code have the same problem, the 2nd ajax call is updated 4 or 5 seconds after the images .... this means that the complete response form server is coming befor the table is full updated. And moving the complete var outside the onclick function makes it fail completly.... any help???

Comment: I don't understand. What do images have to do with this? You know images will still have to load on their own, right? the complete callback is for the ajax only, not additional content returned by the ajax request. Your question doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: sorry the problem are not images, but the animated icon that appears when we are waiting for a ajax request to complete.So my problem is that i have 2 ajax requests and after the first is completed i get the ajaxComplete global function triggered but i need it to only be triggered when all ajax request are completed...

Comment: Unfortunately you can't stop that event from firing at that point in time since in fact all ajax requests ARE complete, at which point the second begins. don't use the global ajax methods.